# how to show xml data and find which one the user clicked on?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, xml

I am using asp.net and have an xml file like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="Style.css"?>
<CATALOG>
<note>
    <TITLE>Tutorial</TITLE>
    <Tut>
        <Episode>Episode 1</Episode>
        <Link>http://www.link1.com</Link>
    </Tut>
    <Tut>
        <Episode>Episode 2</Episode>
        <Link>http://www.link2.com</Link>
    </Tut>
    <Tut>
        <Episode>Episode 3</Episode>
        <Link>http://www.link3.com</Link>
    </Tut>
    <Tut>
        <Episode>Episode 4</Episode>
        <Link>http://www.link4.com</Link>
    </Tut>
</note>
</CATALOG>
```

I am trying to show the xml data in data.aspx 
 and i only want to show episodes vertically like :
Episode 1
Episode 2
Episode 3
Episode 4
so my first part of the question is, do I have to use a gridview or can I use anything else? 
and for the second part, when the user clicks on episode 1 I want to get the link of it , which in this case is "http://www.link1.com" (but I am not showing it here) and set it in to a string variable either in code behind or a session maybe! how can I do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer1:** : If you have to use only two fields Episode number and Link than I would suggest to use repeater control as it is a light weight control.

Online Example: [MSDN Repeater Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**Answer2:** Deserialize XML to your class object and assign it as a Repeater's data source. And in repeater add link button and display set text value as Episode and in href set Link.

Online Example: [XML Deserialization and Serialization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part)

Comment: thanks for the reply. repeater sound like a good idea i think ill use it but the second part, even if i use link button i wont be able to get the url and pass it to a variable !technically, i dont want to redirect the user to the link, i just wanna get the link and assign it to a variable!

Comment: oh ok. So in that case you can use label and textbox. Label will display the name of the episode and textbox will display the url of that episode. Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it is helpful.

Comment: u mean like this: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="<%#XPath("Link")%>"></asp:TextBox> . i get the following error: Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. AND THIS IS THE RED PART: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="<%#XPath("Link")%>"></asp:TextBox><br />

Answer (score 0):

For your second part i prefer using xml to linq :

```
  XElement myXML = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\episode.xml");
  var tutDescendantsList = (from ep in myXML.Descendants("Tut")
                            select new { Episode = ep.Element("Episode").Value, Link = ep.Element("Link").Value }).ToList();
```

To get The elements from **tutDescendantsList :**

```
  string myfirstEpisode = tutDescendantsList[0].Episode;
  string myfirstLink = tutDescendantsList[0].Link;
```